# Exchange MAPI Authentication Loop

Tags: 15.10, email, authentication, evolution

Ubuntu 15.10
Evolution 3.16.15

Trying to access my work's Exchange MOBI server (curse you, proprietary Activesync), but authentication just hangs and continually asks for my password.

User and server are both as given to me by IT, although the domain may be incorrect, although unlikely. Password is also definitively correct.

They're in the following format:

Server: remote.org.co.uk

User: user.xyz.local or user (IT wasn't sure which format Evolution prefers)

Domain: xyz.local

What might I be missing out? Or shall I just badger IT to enable EWS/IMAP?

Comment: Is this an O365 subscription? However, Wiki in Ubuntu gives an explanation for [**Evolution Exchange**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EvolutionExchange) which might help you with. And a [**video**](https://youtu.be/EqU7ZZPo9Og) too

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen elsewhere that you might be able to fix this problem by removing winbind:

```
sudo apt-get remove winbind.
```

Try your luck. Worked for me.